# Jsoup tagName() gives wrong tag

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have following piece of HTML:

```
    <p>                         
     <a href="http://www.today.com/video/jill-martin-rescues-savannah-guthrie-from-her-guest-room-mess-604921923959" rel="nofollow"> Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess </a>   
    <a href="http://www.today.com/video/4-simple-ways-to-clear-your-clutter-this-year-596741699678" rel="nofollow"> 4 simple ways to clear your clutter this year </a>   
    <a href="http://www.today.com/video/staying-home-on-new-years-eve-great-ideas-to-celebrate-at-home-594027587814" rel="nofollow"> Staying home on New Year's Eve? Great ideas to celebrate at home </a>   
    <a href="http://www.today.com/video/heres-how-to-set-a-functional-christmas-table-591622211749" rel="nofollow"> Here's how to set a functional Christmas table </a>    
    </p>
```

This piece is from the web page `http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861`

And piece of code:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861").get(); 
    String tag = null;
    for (Element element : document.select("*") ) { 
        tag = element.tagName();

        if ( "a".equalsIgnoreCase( tag ) ) {
            LOGGER.info("element : {}; nextElementSibling: {}", element.ownText(), element.nextElementSibling() );
        }


        if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(element.ownText(), "Jill Martin rescues Savannah") ) {
            LOGGER.info("element : {}; nextElementSibling: {}", element.ownText(), element.nextElementSibling() );
            LOGGER.info("tag : {}; nextNodeSibling: {}", tag, element.nextSibling() );
            LOGGER.info("element : {}; previousElementSibling: {}", element.ownText(), element.previousElementSibling() );
        }

}
```

The output I am getting:

```
    element : Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess; nextElementSibling: null
    tag : h2; nextNodeSibling:  
    element : Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess; previousElementSibling: null
```

There are a number of issues:

1. From the main HTML source there are many elements tagged as `a` but none from the small HTML piece I am checking against
2. It appears `<a>` is being captured as `<h2>`
3. The `element.nextElementSibling()` is null in most cases

However, if tested against small piece alone the issues disappear. So, it appears Jsoup is not able to recognize tags properly when they appear in a larger HTML source.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

**EDIT 2**

The intention behind the exercise is to clean up a web page. That's why I have iterated through the whole HTML, and not at a particular section as suggested by @Stephan. I only picked a particular section that saw was problematic.

But after checking response from @luksch I looked afresh at the original HTML and found where the anomaly in shooting from. The code overally looks at all tags but gives exception to `a`. In the main source we have `article` followed by `a`, `figure` (which contains `i`, `img`, `img`, `small`, `small`), `h2`. The issue seems like all tags (except `a`) gets removed (which works as required) but their `text` is left behind. That's why I end up being left with `<a href="http://www.today.com/video/jill-martin-rescues-savannah-guthrie-from-her-guest-room-mess-604921923959" rel="nofollow"> Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess </a>` which was not in original HTML source.

The **Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess** is text from `<h2>` but the `<h2>` is gets removed and leaves its text behind. The interesting thing is that Jsoup still recognizes text as coming from `h2`, though the final output doesn't have `h2`.

Comment: The snippet is part of large code. The original link is `http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861`. Therefore the larger doc should be `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-‌​tips-living-luxury-less-t70861").get();`

Comment: The URL gives me a 404

Comment: @luksch, it appears something goes wrong when I copy paste. This is the call: Jsoup.connect("http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861").get();. The word after 'living' is 'luxury' but the copy paste goes wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question then into something that manifests the error in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are giving contains this element:

```
<a class="player-tease-link" href="http://www.today.com/video/jill-martin-rescues-savannah-guthrie-from-her-guest-room-mess-604921923959">
<figure class="player-tease">
  <i class="player-tease-icon icon-video-play"></i>
  <img class="tease-icon-play" src="http://nodeassets.today.com/img/svg/641a740d.video-play-white.svg" alt="Play">
  <img class="tease-image" src="http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/__NEW/tdy_guth_clutter_160120.today-vid-post-small-desktop.jpg" title="Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess" alt="Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess">
  <small class="tease-sponsored">Sponsored Content</small>
  <small class="tease-playing">Now Playing</small>
</figure>
<h2 class="player-tease-headline">Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess</h2>
</a>
```

So it seems that you did compare apples with oranges, meaning that the html snippet you also gave is not part of the original HTML. I guess you used some tool for the extraction that already changed the HTML. Note that the `a` element does not contain any own text!

A good idea would be to follow the advice of @Stephan and learn how to use [CSS selectors properly](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html). This should be much more efficient than selecting all and then filtering manually in your program code. Here is an example of what you could do:

```
 Elements interestingAs = document.select("a:matches(^Jill Martin)");
```

This selects all `a` elements that contain text starting with "Jill Martin".

Comment: I have reviewed the source HTML and compared with final output I am getting, and found the anomaly. In a nutshell some tags are getting removed but leaving behind their `text`. If the parent doesn't get removed the text left behind gets allocated to this tag (parent). We end up with the final output having tags with wrong text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the selector need to be more specific.

Instead of `document.select("*")`, try `document.select("a")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible to me. The following program prints out exactly what you would expect:

```
String html = ""
        +"<p>"
        +"    <a href=\"http://www.today.com/video/jill-martin-rescues-savannah-guthrie-from-her-guest-room-mess-604921923959\" rel=\"nofollow\"> Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess </a>  "
        +"    <a href=\"http://www.today.com/video/4-simple-ways-to-clear-your-clutter-this-year-596741699678\" rel=\"nofollow\"> 4 simple ways to clear your clutter this year </a>  "
        +"    <a href=\"http://www.today.com/video/staying-home-on-new-years-eve-great-ideas-to-celebrate-at-home-594027587814\" rel=\"nofollow\"> Staying home on New Year's Eve? Great ideas to celebrate at home </a>  "
        +"    <a href=\"http://www.today.com/video/heres-how-to-set-a-functional-christmas-table-591622211749\" rel=\"nofollow\"> Here's how to set a functional Christmas table </a>   "
        +"</p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String tag = null;
for (Element element : doc.select("*") ) { 
    tag = element.tagName();

    if ( "a".equalsIgnoreCase( tag ) ) {
        System.out.println("element : "+element.ownText()+"; nextElementSibling: "+element.nextElementSibling()+"" );

    }
    if ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(element.ownText(), "Jill Martin rescues Savannah") ) {
        System.out.println("element : "+element.ownText()+"; nextElementSibling: "+element.nextElementSibling()+"" );
        System.out.println("tag : "+tag+"; nextNodeSibling: "+element.nextSibling()+"" );
        System.out.println("element : "+element.ownText()+"; previousElementSibling: "+element.previousElementSibling()+"" );   
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
element : Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess; nextElementSibling: <a href="http://www.today.com/video/4-simple-ways-to-clear-your-clutter-this-year-596741699678" rel="nofollow"> 4 simple ways to clear your clutter this year </a>
tag : a; nextNodeSibling:  
element : Jill Martin rescues Savannah Guthrie from her guest room mess; previousElementSibling: null
element : 4 simple ways to clear your clutter this year; nextElementSibling: <a href="http://www.today.com/video/staying-home-on-new-years-eve-great-ideas-to-celebrate-at-home-594027587814" rel="nofollow"> Staying home on New Year's Eve? Great ideas to celebrate at home </a>
element : Staying home on New Year's Eve? Great ideas to celebrate at home; nextElementSibling: <a href="http://www.today.com/video/heres-how-to-set-a-functional-christmas-table-591622211749" rel="nofollow"> Here's how to set a functional Christmas table </a>
element : Here's how to set a functional Christmas table; nextElementSibling: null
```

Maybe you use a faulty JSoup version? The above was run with version 1.8.3

Comment: The snippet is part of large code. I just extracted the part I thought was not working. Generally, I am trying to parse the content at `http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861` (which contain the snippet I posted). Instead of `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);` try `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861").get();`

Comment: Something wrong with with previous copy paste. Right call is `Jsoup.connect("http://www.today.com/home/decorating-ideas-david-bromstad-shares-tips-living-luxury-less-t70861").get();`